# how do you terminate a thread in google or tools (SCIP)

Tags: python, multithreading, or-tools, scip

Using:

```py
solver = pywraplp.Solver("assignement", pywraplp.Solver.SCIP_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
```

and setting multiple threads with

```py
solver.SetNumThreads(4)
```

How do I stop all the threads once one of them found the solution?
Currently the script runs until all of them find a solution.

I can make them stop by inserting a time-limit:

```py
solver.SetTimeLimit(num_minutes_for_limit*60*1000)
```

but it is still a waste of time.

Comment: I've never used any of those packages, but the documentation for `pwwraplp` looks to have an `InterruptSolve` method. Based on the wording of your post you seem to know when one thread has found a solution. Could you then call `InterruptSolver` to stop the Solver? // https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/linear_solver/pywraplp.html#Solver.InterruptSolve

Comment: SCIP is not compiled with MT support. It is too buggy.